# Group by a column in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Please, Help me to group the Data by the  column FFP_Centers__c  in a visualforce page as in the attached Screenshot. The code below give no error, but i do not know how to group the result by a field. I need the structure of the code for the grouping

```
public class InventoryReport {
  public List<AggregateResult> allproduct{get;set;}
  public InventoryReport() {
   allproduct = [
  SELECT  FFP_Centers__c, Product_Hiden_Name__c, UM__c ,SUM(On_Hand__c)onHand,  SUM(Pending__c)pending,  SUM(Available__c)avail 
  FROM Articles_Containers__c 
  WHERE IsOpened__c = 1
  GROUP BY  FFP_Centers__c, Product_Hiden_Name__c , UM__c 
  HAVING SUM(On_Hand__c) >0 
  ORDER BY Product_Hiden_Name__c, UM__c limit 1000];
  }
}
```

//the body of my visualforce Page

```
 <div class="table">
         <div class="tableHeader">       
            <th>CENTER </th>
            <th>ITEM</th> 
            <th>UNIT OF MEASURE </th> 
            <th>ON HAND </th> 
            <th>PENDING </th> 
            <th>AVAILABLE </th>
        </div>
      <apex:repeat value="{!allproduct}" var="a">        
  <tr>
     <td>{!a['FFP_Centers__c']}</td>
     <td>{!a['Product_Hiden_Name__c'] }</td>
     <td>{!a['UM__c']}</td>
     <td>{!a['OnHand']}</td> 
     <td>{!a['Pending']}</td>
     <td>{!a['avail']}</td>
  </tr>   
        </apex:repeat>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What problem are you having specifically? Please read about [ask] and then [edit] your question to include details about what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Please help me

Comment: You already have some code, but what's the observed behavior? What's not working? We need something to go off of, either code that we can copy-paste in to our own org to try and solve (which we can't), or an error message or unexpected behavior youre observing (which you haven't told us).

Comment: The code give no error, but i do not know how to group the result by a field. I need the structure of the code for the grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to change your data structure into a map:

```
public Map<String, List<AggregateResult>> allProduct { get; set; }
public InventoryReport() {
  allProduct = new Map<String, List<AggregateResult>>();
  AggregateResult[] results = [
    SELECT  FFP_Centers__c center, Product_Hiden_Name__c name, UM__c um,
            SUM(On_Hand__c)onHand,  SUM(Pending__c)pending,  
            SUM(Available__c)avail 
    FROM Articles_Containers__c 
    WHERE IsOpened__c = 1
    GROUP BY  FFP_Centers__c, Product_Hiden_Name__c , UM__c 
    HAVING SUM(On_Hand__c) >0 
    ORDER BY Product_Hiden_Name__c, UM__c limit 1000];
  for(AggregateResult result: results) {
    String center = (String)result.get('center');
    if(!allProduct.containsKey(center)) {
      allProduct.put(center, new AggregateResult[0]);
    }
    allProduct.get(center).add(result);
  }
}
```

Then, in your VF, you can iterate over the keys, and then the values within:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!allProduct}" var="key">
  <tr><th>{!key}</th></tr>
  <apex:repeat value="{!allProduct[key]}" var="row">
    <tr>
      <td>{!row['name']}</td>
      <td>{!row['um']}</td>
      <td>{!row['onHand']}</td>
      <td>{!row['pending']}</td>
      <td>{!row['avail']}</td>
    </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```